# Getting "Invalid exit definition" on Compilation of Sails Helper (Sails v1.0)

Tags: sails.js

I'm getting the error

```
Invalid exit definition ("success").  Must be a dictionary-- i.e. plain JavaScript object like `{}`.
Invalid exit definition ("error").  Must be a dictionary-- i.e. plain JavaScript object like `{}`.
```

when doing `sails lift`. The error is on `getRole.js`

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Get Role',


  description: '',


  inputs: {
    user_id: {
      friendlyName: 'User Id',
      description: 'The ID of the user to check role',
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  },

  exits: {
    success: function (role){
      return role;
    },
    error: function (message) {
      return message;
    }
  },


  fn: function (inputs, exits) {
    User.findOne({ id: inputs.user_id } , function (err, user) {
      if (err) return exits.err(err);
      return exits.success(user.role);
    });
  }
};
```

This is a new error, and looking at my git, nothing has changed in my code since it successfully compiled. I understand the Sails version (v1.0) I'm using in beta, so I'm taking that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Exits cannot be defined as functions. There is a special syntax ([Machine Spec](http://node-machine.org/spec/machine)) to define exits. In your example this should work:

```
exits: {
    error: {
        description: 'Unexpected error occurred.',
    },

    success: {
        description: 'Role was succesffuly fetched'
    }
},
```

You can read more info about helper exits here: https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers

Answer (score 0):

May changes occur on the last release 1.0.0-38. I've not checked underneath yet, but the way to execute helpers changed: on `.exec()` I get errors. Now, use `.switch()`;